# osx 10.7.5 built-in apache 403 forbidden for sites/default/files/styles

Tags: 7, files

this really drives me crazy .. BTW [here](http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion) is a really nice tutorial i tried - everything. believe me ...
from adding users to groups, running apache as different user, chALOT -R (even chmod a+rwx), copying the original httpd.conf back, enabled UserDir, added attributes like

```
sudo chmod -R +a "group:_www allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" Sites
```

but .. i'm not an expirienced sys admin // ---

i try to use both - WebServer and User location as Document root

```
setup
/etc/apache2/http.conf

setup
/etc/apache2/users/me.conf
```

and actually all seems to work fine. so AllowOverride and FollowSymLinks set

**except:** sites/default/files/styles/

image styles do not work i get 403 for requests like

```
sites/default/files/styles/fancy/public/animage.jpg
```

original images show up ..

maybe related to the [7.20 issue](http://drupal.org/drupal-7.20-release-notes) ?!

how can i properly debug this ?

Comment: This is more likely the issue with version 7.20 rather than the OS or server. You can add `$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;` to your `settings.php` to negate the effect of the update.

Comment: god damn. @Indrock - this did the trick .. i lost hours .. thx so much. post it as answer pls. and what about for the production site. does this have any side effects ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more likely to be the issue with the update of Drupal core from 7.19 to 7.20.
As per the release notes, the update was only targeted to address the [Denial-of-Service attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) on the sites powered by Drupal.

You can add:

```
$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

in the `settings.php`, to negate the effect of the update. As per the side effects, this will remove this security fix. I wouldn't recommend you do this on production.

**existing patch:**

```
--- a/modules/image/image.module
+++ b/modules/image/image.module
@@ -993,7 +993,7 @@ function image_style_url($style_name, $path) {
// The token query is added even if the 'image_allow_insecure_derivatives'
// variable is TRUE, so that the emitted links remain valid if it is changed
// back to the default FALSE.
-  $token_query = array(IMAGE_DERIVATIVE_TOKEN =>  image_style_path_token($style_name, $path));
+  $token_query = array(IMAGE_DERIVATIVE_TOKEN => image_style_path_token($style_name, file_stream_wrapper_uri_normalize($path)));
```

works, and $conf can be removed !

I've answered a similar question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/63232/6461).

**Note:** I'm making this as community wiki, so that someone working on Drupal security (hopefully from the security team) or [anyone who is interested](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Be_bold) could add more to it.

Comment: with this [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1923554#comment-7110348) i could remove the $conf again

Comment: @rémy Good to know that :-) You can edit this post and add that in, also it would be good if you give your feedback (regarding the patch) on the same issue on drupal.org

Comment: actually i commented the issue on drupal.org. but it only shows up when i'm logged in ...