# How do I remove the itok token from the image URLs?

Tags: 8, media

How do I remove the itok token from the image URLs?

I found an article discussing it, but it only works for Drupal 7 (https://www.drupal.org/node/1934498).

Some articles explains why Drupal adds tokens to the image URLs.

- http://www.unimitysolutions.com/blog/image-style-token-itok-drupal
- [Why is Drupal adding token on image url](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66552/why-is-drupal-adding-token-on-image-url)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While it's recommended to keep the `itok` parameter, it is configurable.

You can suppress it from output using the `image.settings` config setting `suppress_itok_output`

```
  // The token query is added even if the
  // 'image.settings:allow_insecure_derivatives' configuration is TRUE, so
  // that the emitted links remain valid if it is changed back to the default
  // FALSE. However, sites which need to prevent the token query from being
  // emitted at all can additionally set the
  // 'image.settings:suppress_itok_output' configuration to TRUE to achieve
  // that (if both are set, the security token will neither be emitted in the
  // image derivative URL nor checked for in
  // \Drupal\image\ImageStyleInterface::deliver()).
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!image!src!Entity!ImageStyle.php/function/ImageStyle%3A%3AbuildUrl/8.2.x

Comment: Thanks, i add `$config['image.settings']['suppress_itok_output'] = TRUE;` to my site's settings.php file and it workd fine.

Comment: And another configuration `$config['image.settings']['allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;`

Comment: Additional Info. if site is accessed from https. make sure to enable "allow_insecure_derivatives" to TRUE as mentioned by shi jack.

Comment: @shijack It works for me, but in some other way that is not usable. I set it on configuration and work first time, for the second page is not working, so I disable the configuration and reload the page still not working, again applying the changes and reload the page then it works and show the image. BTW Thanks.

Comment: Added the examples from @shijack to the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your settings.php (or local.settings.php):

```
$config['image.settings']['suppress_itok_output'] = TRUE;
```