# How do I get the cache string?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8, CSS files, images and many other files, are cached by appending a token at the end, as in */sites/default/files/styles/lrg_thumbnail/public/p2i-product_1_zoomout.png?itok=DroPCbms*.

Notice the *itok=DroPCbms* part.

What Drupal function returns this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to CSS/JS the `itok` is not for caching, but for DoS protection, see this question
[Why are tokens added to image URLs?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66552/why-are-tokens-added-to-image-urls)

The token is generated in
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Entity%21ImageStyle.php/function/ImageStyle%3A%3AgetPathToken/8.2.x