# Image style doesn't rebuild after image style flushed

Tags: 7, media

I have practically the same problem as here : https://drupal.org/node/2187443

I've flushed my image style because I edited this image style. Now when I reload the page where the image style should be shown they are missing (404).

What did I missed? shouldn't it be recreated automatically when styles are removed ?

**Edit :**

I found that images couldn't regenerate if 404 error isn't managed by Drupal. I think its very possible, then I made a change in to my `.htaccess` file to make Drupal manage 404 errors.

I am now getting the 403 error upon all my files, that are still not loading. :(

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Then I add +w on my files directory recursively to make sure the writing permission available for all to avoid 403 but nothing happens.

Comment: Clear cache and check your permissions.

Comment: To be more specific, make sure your permissions follow Drupal's guidelines https://drupal.org/node/244924;

Comment: I'm already using this to fix my drupal permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!!!

After checking that Drupal manages itself 404 errors by checking .htaccess file :

```
# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

I had to put this line into my settings.php... This is in the Drupal 7.20 release notes :

```
$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

[This thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63226/drupal-7-20-image-styles-return-a-url-with-access-denied) saved my day.

Wish helps others.