# fields with Image styles only showing placeholder

Tags: views, media, files

I've got some images that's set to be shown in specific image styles. They appear fine on each node but in teasers and views I only get a placeholder.

The console in Chrome's inspector says:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

The Files folder has permissions set to 775. Should be good, right?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you show field image in views mode teaser?

Comment: yes I do. It's worked fine previously on the same site & content type. Maybe it came from an update like this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63226/drupal-7-20-image-styles-return-a-url-with-access-denied. But I'm not sure what was updated at the time.

Comment: the message "the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" is general. I think, this error because by your code. You can settings show erros (https://www.drupal.org/node/1056468). And if your site not private, can you share your link. I can check help you.

Comment: really appreciate it. The site is private though. The drupal log gives me 2 errors that seems directly linked to this: "The file permissions could not be set on public://styles/image-style-name" + "Failed to create style directory: public://styles/". The weird thing is that both the style and directory exists!

Comment: You can search with keyword is message error. And i think your errors is folder permission. If you have ssh, you can set group permission with command chown.

Comment: I've never used SSH. Can I do it via drush? got drush up & running. If I try to do it via ftp it gives me this error: "Error -140: remote mkdir failed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an overview of how file permissions should be set on a Drupal installation: https://www.drupal.org/node/244924

If you scroll down there is a shell script that you can install on your server and it will fix all file/folder permission errors.

Your issue is definitely a folder permission error, Drupal has to be able to write to the /files folder. It makes new directories for each style, each image, each size so one folder may exist but the others may not be able to be made.

Comment: Thanks, had a friend assist me in SSH'ing the permissions to what they should be and the IMGs are back!